# How to delay a function excecution

Tags: javascript, http, timer, vue.js, flux

I have this situation, i'm building a shopping cart, and  i need to make a http request each time a product is added or its quantity is changed.

I have one button to add 1 unit of a product to the cart, it supposed that each unit added should make the http request, but i want to avoid to make to many calls at once... So i wanted to set a timeout for the request, but if within 3 secs the user clicks again, then i should cancel the last request with old data and then set a new timeout fot the request with the new data.

So i came up with this solution

```
function doRequest(){
  clearTimeout(state.request);
  state.request = setTimeout(updateCartService, 180);      
}
```

The function is inside another function that retrieves the *state* object (A collection of variables and data persistent through all the application). The *updateCarteService* function contains the http request.

However all the requests are still being made, if i click 5 times the button that triggers doRequest, the call i being excecuted 5 times.

Have any idea of what could be wrong or pherhaps a better aproach to achieve my goal?

If it helps i'm bulding the site using vueJs, vuex (flux) and this code is inside an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout takes milliseconds, so you set timout for 180ms, it is too short, try 3000 for example. Here a small jsfiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ShinShil/5fw2c63o/

```
var timeout;
$('#click').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(setText, 3000);
});

function setText() {
    $('#text').append('text');
}
```

Comment: It worked!! ooh i can't believe it was that, i just didn't think about it! Thanks a lot